# Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Tags: sudo

I need to execute the command `sudo fab deps_local`, but I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: I guess you are using this in a django context? If so, are you in a virtual environment? Do you have fabric installed?

Comment: I'm not in a virtual environment. I installed the Fabric using `sudo apt-get install fabric`.

Comment: can you run `fab --list` in the folder in which you have your fab file?

Comment: I don't know where my fab file is.

Comment: Then provide us with more information. What tutorial are you following? Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/adlnet/ADL_LRS#adl-lrs) to install ADL LRS, but I can't.

Comment: The problem you face is not related to ubuntu. It is a python/django problem. My answer should solve it, but I do think this question (about *a particular step in an installation*) is too localized.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to run the command `sudo fab deps_local` you have to be in the directory in which you can find the `fabfile.py`. That file (which is [part of the repository](https://github.com/adlnet/ADL_LRS/blob/master/fabfile.py)) is where you unzipped the ADL LRS folder. If you did not change its name it is called `Django-1.4` (which in this case is a directory, not the name of a software package).